# Flutter SQFLITE: Please explain what factory and this data type Future<List<Trail>> means

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to get SQFlite to work in a flutter.

I'm new to flutter and there are some nagging problems with null safety and new types I'm not familiar with.

On top of the problems.. sometimes it says "List is not a type" which it certainly is.

My own code is located here
https://github.com/bksubhuti/places

I would like to connect it to a futurebuilder or listbuilder UI.

This is a learning app but also one for production later on.
Eventually I want to rewrite book reading app (Tipitaka Pali Projector) based on SQFlite and flutter.

follow a tutorial on trails.  The code is on github.
https://github.com/nhandrew/sqflite_app/blob/main/lib/main.dart

It does not work with null safety

There is another code for a dog tutorial which is the official tutorial for flutter SQLite I don't understand this code
The code is located at this link here

The dog tutorial also has a similar syntax which is new to me.
https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/src/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite.md

I get confused about the factory and this datatype Future<List>
I have never seen this stuff before.

It also has to work with null safety.

It is This part here.. that is confusion

```
 factory Trail.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
return Trail(  
  name: json['name'],
  difficulty: json['difficulty'],
  distance: json['distance']
);
```

}

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(  
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: FutureBuilder<List<Trail>>(
    future: dbService.getTrails(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
            leading: Text(snapshot.data[index].difficulty),
            trailing: Text(snapshot.data[index].distance.toString()),
          );
        });
    }
  )
);
```

}

```
  Future<List<Trail>> getTrails() async {
await initDatabase();
List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Trails');
return list.map((trail) => Trail.fromJson(trail)).toList();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read Dart language tour:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

You can find details on your questions here:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#asynchrony-support

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists

I'll edit my answer to give answers you asked in a comment.

So, let's unpack this part:

```
Future<List<Trail>> getTrails() async {
await initDatabase();
List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Trails');
return list.map((trail) => Trail.fromJson(trail)).toList();
}
```

First of all - the function is asynchronous (as indicated by `async` keyword). This means a few things: this function will be able to run in parallel with other things. This is not technically 100% correct, but let's leave it at this level now.
This parallel run is achieved by the function immediately returning a Future object, and later returning the function value into this Future object. (Actually, Future is returned when it first hits await statement but ignore it for now).
Think of it as ordering food in a restaurant: you place the order, and the waiter immediately puts an empty plate in front of you (the plate is the Future object). While waiting for your dinner, you get to do other things - go to the restroom, have some drinks, etc. Eventually, the food will appear in your plate. Food is the object that the Future will eventually hold.
I'm trying here to simply explain a very complex topic - you should learn about this separately, it will really help you a lot. A LOT.

So this kinda explains what this means: `Future<List<Trail>>`. Your function will immediately return a Future object. But not any Future object, but the one that will hold a specific return value once the function completes. This value will be of List type: but not any List type - it will hold a list that will have only Trail object values. Hence List is defined as `List<Trail>` (List of Trail objects), and Future is `Future<List<Trail>>` - a Future that will hold a List of Trail objects.

Next, you are calling `await initDatabase();`. your initDatabase is async itself, which gives you an option to run some other things while you are waiting for the database to initialise. You could have for example:

```
var i=initDatabase();
print('Doing some work while the database is being initialized');
await i; // now I'm done, nothing for me to do until the database is initialized, so I'll just wait for that
List<Map> list =...
```

Again - here you really need to understand your async/await and Future (or Promises as they are called in JavaScript).

The rest should be easy:

```
List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Trails');
```

Your rawQuery is async - and you decided to wait for it, since there is nothing else for you to do until query is done. The query will return a List - assuming here it will be a List of database Rows. Each Row is presented as a Map object, so List will not be any list - but a List of Map: `List<Map>`.

Finally - you convert `List<Map>` that is returned by query into `List<Trail>` - since this is the value you should return. Remember - function returns `Future<List<Trail>>`, so your final return statement needs to return `List<Trail>`. Remember: Future was returned already when you called the function.

Comment: Can you explain the data type with eh angle brackets? <List<Trail>>.                   
       Future<List<Trail>> getTrails() async {
await initDatabase();
List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Trails');
return list.map((trail) => Trail.fromJson(trail)).toList();

Comment: I expanded my answer with more details, I hope it helps.

Comment: That explains a lot.  I appreciate it..  I can understand the List object and the Future type (seems similar to c++ template List)  but there is a double type cast that the compiler is complaining about that confuses me as the root problem. 

 final List<Map<String, dynamic>> which is what the dog and other sqlite tutorial accepts from the sqlite.query call

Comment: The project https://github.com/nhandrew/sqflite_app works fine if you download it and compile it.  However, there are mak settings (not sure where)  which cause this project to compile with low strictness.  It would be good if i could get ANY project that does a sqlite DB hit in a similar way but with all the null safety.  If it does not compile, i cannot learn anything.  If you look at the github issue i posted, it does not work if you simply copy over the essential files yml file, lib/ assets/